# How to show that lim inf $p_n$ ≤ lim inf $q_n$ ≤ lim sup $q_n$ ≤ lim sup $p_n$

Tags: analysis

Let $(p_n)$ be a sequence of nonnegative numbers, and for each $n ∈ N$, let $q_n$ =
$\frac{1}{n}(p_1 + p_2 + · · · + p_n)$.

Show that:
$lim$ $inf$ $p_n$ ≤ $lim$ $inf$ $q_n$ ≤ $lim$ $sup$ $q_n$ ≤ $lim$ $sup$ $p_n$

Comment: Instead of writing `$lim$ $inf$ $p_n$ ≤` and so on, you can put it all into one big math block (using commands for liminf and ≤) like so: `$\liminf p_n \leq \liminf q_n$` makes $\liminf p_n \leq \liminf q_n$. Looks a little nicer, and is a lot faster to write. For more details you can see, for instance, [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ and $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that $\forall n \ge n_0$ $p_n \le \limsup p + {\epsilon\over 2}$

Then  $\forall n \ge n_0$
$$\begin{align}
q_n &= {1\over n}(\sum_{k=1}^{n_0} p_k +\sum_{k=n_0+1}^{n} p_k)
\\&\le {1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{n_0} p_k +{n-n_0\over n} (\limsup p + {\epsilon\over 2})\\
&\le {1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{n_0} p_k + \limsup p + {\epsilon\over 2}
\end{align}$$

Since $\sum_{k=1}^{n_0} p_k$ is finite, ${1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{n_0} p_k \rightarrow 0$ thus let $n_1 \in \Bbb N$ such that $\forall n\le n_1$, ${1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{n_0} p_k \le{\epsilon\over2}$

Thus $\forall n \ge \max(n_0, n_1)$, you have :

$$
q_n \le {\epsilon\over2} + \limsup p +{\epsilon\over2} = \limsup p +\epsilon
$$

Thus $\limsup q \le \limsup p$

Same for $\liminf$

Comment: I apologize for my previous answer which was very, **very** wrong...